# How to output jsignature after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am using the jsignature plugin (http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature) to allow users to 'sign' a form. This all works correctly however I am trying to output the signature after page reload into the same canvas so it can be further edited if necessary (this only happens if the form validation fails for whatever reason).

What I cannot understand is that I can redraw it correctly if i do it before reloading the page, but if i try after reloading then i get a "Error: jSignature is unable to find import plugin with for format 'undefined'" error and it won't work.

So if i use the following JS code on the submit button it works correctly (clears the canvas and then redraws it):

```
    $("#signature").jSignature({'UndoButton': true});
    $('#qmembershipsubmit').click(function(e) {
        var datapair = $('#signature').jSignature("getData","base30");
        var datastr="data:" + datapair.join(",");
        $("#signature").jSignature("reset");
        alert('should be cleared');
        $("#signature").jSignature("importData",datastr);
        return false;
    });
```

However I do not want to do JS form validation and want to pass the value via the form and then reuse it on the following page if necessary. However when i use the following code (so it runs the importData command using the string stored in #signature_capture2) i get the unable to find import plugin error:

```
    $("#signature").jSignature({'UndoButton': true});
    if($('#recreatesig').val()=='1')
    {
        alert('recreate');
        $("#signature").jSignature("importData",$('#signature_capture2').val());
    }
    $('#qmembershipsubmit').click(function(e) {
        var datapair = $('#signature').jSignature("getData","base30");
        var datastr="data:" + datapair.join(",");
        $("#signature_capture2").val(datastr);
    });
```

The value of datastr matches the value stored in signature_capture2 so I cannot for the life of me see why this isn't working as surely it is effectively doing the same thing (and it's reloading on the same page so the same plugins/js scripts are included on both).

If anyone could shed any light it would be massively appreciated.

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using jSignature("getData","default"), this gets the data out in base64, can be used on img tags and works when using importData too.